# How to dynamically generate column of particular row of table in html through JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I m stuck here so please help me out. I have a html table which look like this

```
ID | Name | DOB | Action|
```

And when i click on Action, Then it must appear like this,

```
ID | Name | DOB | Select| Reject|
```

Please help in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base example to help you out.

I made a fiddle, with a table with 2 **td**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td id='td2'>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then i binded a click event on the second **td** so that when you click it, it removes the last td of each row and adds 2 extra td's. Here's the jquery function:

```
$('#td2').on("click",function(){
    $('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).children('td').last().remove();
        var myTD = "<td>3</td><td>4</td>";
        $(this).append(myTD);
    });
})
```

here's a jsfiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UP2PJ/)